# Where can I get the font Cloister Black BT Regular and have it embedded in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts

I had this font installed on my mac and never had issues with it - then my hard drive went and when the time came to print existing files (Award certificates) that I had on file it appears correct in AI but when I convert to a PDF it says something about not embedding due to licensing restrictions? I will purchase if necessary but I want to be sure when I purchase that it will work. When I checked the info on a font I downloaded for free it said it was embeddable but its not the case … PLEASE ADVISE as I'm on a deadline and can't get this resolved no matter what I try.I've not had this happen with any other fonts that Ive reinstalled only this one. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What program are you using to create those PDFs. That’s the source of the problem, not the font (at least in my opinion).

Comment: If you purchase the correct license, the font will embed. *"on a font I downloaded for free"* It's free... they don't *have* to be accurate with *anything*.

Comment: There are two questions here. The first one, where can I get the font? is resource gathering, and off topic here. The second issue is somewhat phrased as a need for tech support. We don't have enough information to say whether it's a problem that's likely to be encountered by anyone other than you. Please add a lot more information, and try to describe your problem better. At the moment, it sounds like just converting all text objects to outlines would achieve what you want, but it's so obfuscated I can't state anything for sure (I can't even tell if it's definitely a vector file).

Answer (score 0):

It must be your version of the software...Look what I got...(with CS6)

[image]